# R: optimising a function with a dataset

Tags: r, function

I have the following function:

```
modifyNameFunction <- function(x) {
  if (x== "A")
    return("Blue")
    if (x== "B")
    return("Red")
  if (x== "C")
    return("Green")
  if (x== "D")
    return("Grey")
    return(x)
}
```

which I take from the following dataset:

```
df =
Code Meaning
A    Blue
B    Red
C    Green
D    Grey
```

Is there a way to make the `modifyNameFunction` more efficient using `df`? I have tried:

```
modifyNameFunction <- function(x) {
  if (x== df$Code)
    return(df$Meaning)
    return(x)
}
```

When I use such function I get the following error: `the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep `df` as it is and you can use `match` :

```
x <- c('D', 'B')
df$Meaning[match(x, df$Code)]
#[1] "Grey" "Red"
```

Or you can use a named vector to subset.

```
setNames(df$Meaning, df$Code)[x]
#    D      B 
#"Grey"  "Red"
```